# Excel: Power Query - how to repeat block of code for each row in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

I have JSON in format like this:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "2021-01-01",
      "data": 10
    },
    {
      "date": "2021-01-02",
      "data": 20
    },
    {
      "date": "2021-01-03",
      "data": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm able to write this code which does exaclty what I want:

```m
let
    Source = Json.Document(...),
    data = Source[data],
    #"ToTable" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    
// Block 1 Start
    Column1 = #"ToTable"{0}[Column1], //Gets Record from 1st "data" Array item
    #"ToTable1" = Record.ToTable(Column1), //Create table with two columns (key, value)
    #"Transpose1" = Table.Transpose(#"ToTable1"), //Transpose the table
    #"Headers1" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transpose1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]), //Get headers from the 1st row (key names)
    #"ChangeType1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Headers1",{{"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, type any}}), //Change Type
// Block 1 End

// Block 2 Start
    Column2 = #"ToTable"{1}[Column1], //Gets Record from 2nd "data" Array item
    #"ToTable2" = Record.ToTable(Column2),
    #"Transpose2" = Table.Transpose(#"ToTable2"),
    #"Headers2" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transpose2", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"ChangeType2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Headers2",{{"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, type any}}),
// Block 2 End

// Block 3 Start
    Column3 = #"ToTable"{2}[Column1], //Gets Record from 3rd "data" Array item
    #"ToTable3" = Record.ToTable(Column3),
    #"Transpose3" = Table.Transpose(#"ToTable3"),
    #"Headers3" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transpose3", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"ChangeType3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Headers3",{{"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, type any}}),
// Block 3 End

    TheTable = Table.Combine({ChangeType1, ChangeType2, ChangeType3}) //Combines tables together
in
    TheTable
```

### BUT

This all is OK for 3 items in "data" Array, not when there are hundreds of them.

Is there some trick how to repeat `Code block` for each row in `data[Column1]`, get a `List` of Tables (ChangeTypeX) to use in `Table.Combine`?

Comment: What am I missing?  It appears you want to have a result with two columns `date` and `data`. If that is the case, all you need to do is expand the table that results from Step 3. `Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"ToTable", "Column1", {"date", "data"}, {"date", "data"})`  If you want something else, please edit your question to add a screenshot of the desired results from the data you show.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Nice, thanks! Please transform your comment to an answer. I'm just curious - is there some trick to get easily these lists `{"date", "data"}, {"date", "data"}` (in my real case there are tens of properties in each Object in data Array).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*these lists*".  In your Power Query, **Lists** would refer to the columns and the rows would be referred to as **Records**.   So step 3 would be returning a list of records.  I don't know what **List** would refer to as part of a JSON structure.  Perhaps a different question showing exactly what you mean would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to have a result with two columns `date` and `data`. If that is the case, all you need to do is expand the table that results from Step 3.

Merely click the double headed arrow at the top of the column

[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\new 3.json")),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"date", "data"}, {"date", "data"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

**Result**
[image]

*You should also set the data types after you have expanded the columns*

Answer (score 2):

Lets start from beginning

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(...),
    data = Source[data],
    #"ToTable1" = Record.ToTable(Column1)
```

Now we have `List` of `Record`s stored in `#"ToTable1"[Column1]`. (Because table Columns are `List`s.)

So we can use [`List.Transform` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-transform) to manipulate with each `Item` of this `List`.

Syntax is

```m
List.Transform(list as list, transform as function) as list
```

So we need some transform function which works with each Item of the List separately. Let modify a Code Block from the Original question.

```m
MyFunc = (ColumnRow) =>
let
  #"ToTableX" = Record.ToTable(ColumnRow),
  #"TransposeX" = Table.Transpose(#"ToTableX"),
  #"HeadersX" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"TransposeX", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
  #"ChangeTypeX" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"HeadersX",{{"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, type any}})
in

#"ChangeTypeX"
```

So whole `List.Tranform` function code looks like

```m
List.Transform(#"ToTable1"[Column1], MyFunc)
```

This returns a `List` of `Table`s which could be used in [`Table.Combine` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-combine).

```m
MyResultTable = Table.Combine(List.Transform(#"ToTable1"[Column1], MyFunc))
```

## Put it all together

```m
let
  Source = Json.Document(...),
  data = Source[data],
  #"ToTable1" = Record.ToTable(Column1)
// End of original code used here
  
  MyList = #"ToTable1"[Column1], //For better readability
  MyFunc = (ColumnRow) =>
  let
    #"ToTableX" = Record.ToTable(ColumnRow),
    #"TransposeX" = Table.Transpose(#"ToTableX"),
    #"HeadersX" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"TransposeX", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"ChangeTypeX" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"HeadersX",{{"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, type any}})
  in
  
  #"ChangeTypeX",
  
  MyResultTable = Table.Combine(List.Transform(MyList, MyFunc))
   
  in
  
  MyResultTable
```