# JSON conversion in Power Query - how automatically get list of object property names

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, json

This is a question based on comment in [Excel: Power Query - how to repeat block of code for each row in a table](https://superuser.com/q/1689105).

Let's say we have a JSON with array of object each with `N` properies:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "data1": 1,
      "data2": 2,
      //...
      "dataN": N
    },
    {
      "data1": 11,
      "data2": 12,
      //...
      "dataN": 1N
    },
    {
      "data1": 21,
      "data2": 22,
      //...
      "dataN": 2N
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get a table with column for each data property.

```
+---------+---------+---+--------+
| data1   | data2   | … | DataN  |
+---------+---------+---+--------+
|       1 |       2 | … | N      |
|      11 |      12 | … | 1N     |
|      21 |      22 | … | 2N     |
+---------+---------+---+--------+
```

Initial steps are

```m
Source = Json.Document(...),
data = Source[data],
ToTable = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
```

Then [`Table.ExpandRecordColumn`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-expandrecordcolumn) syntax is

```m
Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ToTable, "Column1", {"data1", "data2" ... "dataN"}, {"data1", "data2" ... "dataN"})
```

This is really tedious to write it manually. How to obtain a lists containing names of JSON object properties (`{"data1", "data2" ... "dataN"}`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little embarrassing, I figured it out only a moment after I spend some time and effort to formulate my question. So I hope it will help to  others.

The solution is [`Record.FieldNames`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-expandrecordcolumn).

If all object in JSON `data` Array have same set of properties, we can just extract `FieldNames` from any `Record`.

```m
Source = Json.Document(...),
data = Source[data],
ToTable = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
// Original code end

// Gets list of FieldNames from the first row in Column1
Headers = Record.FieldNames(ToTable[Column1]{0}),
// Creates table with columns acc. to List in Head
Result = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ToTable, "Column1", Headers, Headers)
```

Or you can just click to button in the GUI. For details see [Ron Rosenfeld's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1689268/483121) to my other answer mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I find that, often, the act of formulating the question so it is clear to others can also make the solution clear to myself.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, this phenomen is even named [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :).

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thanks for the reference.